# Use Remainders of modulo operator in R for logical comparisons

Tags: r, logical-operators

I noticed recently a weird behavior when I wanted to differentiate a variable by the remainder.

```
x <- ifelse(48.002 %% 1 == 0.002, 1, 0)
```

However, testing the logic operation above showed this is not true.

```
48.002 %% 1 == 0.002
[1] FALSE
```

While if I use `>=` instead of `==`, it could identify correctly:

```
48.002 %% 1 >= 0.002
[1] TRUE
 48.001 %% 1 >= 0.002
[1] FALSE
```

Could someone please help me understand why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by **differentiate a variable by the remainder**?

Comment: `48.002 %% 1` is `0.0020000000000024443` not `0.002`